# print section(s) of a file when section's content match a pattern

Tags: awk, sed, text-parsing

I've been using [Go Replay](https://github.com/buger/goreplay) to capture HTTP trafic.
Now I'm left with a text file where each request is separated by ''

```
1 10ef8cc77b962b383557265f5eb1922e5affa88e 1518086364760738000
HEAD /xyz/
Host: d.e.f
User-Agent: ...
...
Connection: Keep-Alive



1 3534a2e1d670c596a673a706c3031a6bec9d6b06 1518086364994132000
HEAD /abc/
Host: a.b.c
User-Agent: ...
...
Connection: Keep-Alive



1 06891fdbebd48cb23ffe6ed5964c3fadcceb9199 1518086366027862000
HEAD /abc/
Host: a.b.c
User-Agent: ...
...
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

I want to extracts (print) only the requests from that file that match with the given Header `Host: a.b.c` :

```
1 3534a2e1d670c596a673a706c3031a6bec9d6b06 1518086364994132000
HEAD /abc/
Host: a.b.c
User-Agent: ...
...
Connection: Keep-Alive



1 06891fdbebd48cb23ffe6ed5964c3fadcceb9199 1518086366027862000
HEAD /abc/
Host: a.b.c
User-Agent: ...
...
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Note: the input file might also contains binary data for POST requests (like `Content-Type: image/png`):

```
POST /...
Content-Length: 26892

-----------------------------19579713013480936471158807818
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"; filename="__fileCreatedFromDataURI__.png"
Content-Type: image/png

<89>PNG
^Z
^@^@^@^MIHDR^@
...
```

Which can possibly disrupt the processing ...

Is it achievable in one go with tools like awk/sed ? Or might it requires to write a plain script (with Python for ex) ? I think I could split the input to several files but it would result in way too much amount of files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU **`awk`** approach:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ RS=ORS="" }/Host: a.b.c/; END{ ORS=""; print }' file
```

The output:

```
1 3534a2e1d670c596a673a706c3031a6bec9d6b06 1518086364994132000
HEAD /abc/
Host: a.b.c
User-Agent: ...
...
Connection: Keep-Alive



1 06891fdbebd48cb23ffe6ed5964c3fadcceb9199 1518086366027862000
HEAD /abc/
Host: a.b.c
User-Agent: ...
...
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Comment: Wow it works ! Now it appears that the file contains some binary content (like `Content-Type: image/png`) which makes awk to stop... Any idea ?

Comment: @martin, how does it stop awk from processing? Perhaps, post a verbose error message or share a screenshot

Comment: Well it stops with `Content-Type: image/png

�PNG

4^��|��
       �>;��z�{�u�` and returns the prompt.

Comment: works fine on bash shell and gawk v4.2. Make sure that it's actually awk error and not from preceding tool

Comment: I was using `awk` which was really `mawk` on my system. `gawk` seems to work !